# How to convert property at DbContext/DbSet level?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

Records in my table are stored with a DateTime being in UTC format.
I want to query that table in local time, so I need to convert time stamp to local time when retrieving the records from database.

What I've tried so far is simply converting the DateTime property in DbSet class belonging to DbContext.

```
private System.DateTime UtcTimeStamp;
public System.DateTime TimeStamp
{
    get
    {
        return UtcTimeStamp.ToLocalTime();
    }
    set
    {
        UtcTimeStamp = value;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, the result is the same as without these changes.

However, when I do LINQ query converting the DateTime to local time, it works just fine.

```
records = records.Where(x => x.TimeStamp.ToLocalTime() >= input.StartDate);
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't want to convert it every time I need it as this is ineffective and takes ages.

Comment: You can use [Value conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) to store the data in UTC and *load* it inside the object as local. But that's not good for returning the data and also doesn't work inside the LINQ to Entities queries when translated to sql. Why don't you simply do it other way around - convert the parameters like `input.StartDate` to UTC and use UTC value for comparison?

Comment: If I've done it the other way around, I would get a result in UTC and would still have to convert to Local Time as I want to display in Local Time. It would look odd if somebody selected a filter to start from 3pm, but got results from 1pm.

Comment: I am mostly interested why the conversion on getter doesn't work. It's strange as it looks really straight forward.

Comment: If you need to return the data in local time, then you can combine the two approaches - use value conversions for storing the data, and UTC converted parameters for filtering.

Comment: The conversion in getter doesn't work when the query is translated and executed [server side](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval) as SQL because there are no "object"s there - just table records, so `WHERE table.TimeStamp` has no way to invoke your *object* getter. See [How Queries Work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/overview).

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Thanks a lot for your suggestion to use value conversions and use UTC for filtering. The result is exactly as I needed to be. Thank you!